# How do I work with architectural scales in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, scale

I want to make a floor plan in Inkscape, but cannot see how to set up the units.

The measurements are in inches. However, if I set the display units to inches, then the page is only 8.5 x 11 inches wide. The house is hundreds of inches wide.

I need to work in inches to enter the floor plan, but I need the drawing to fit on a piece of paper. How do I set up the units to do that?

Comment: Typically one would [work in scale](https://davidneat.wordpress.com/methods/working-in-scale/) rather than full size.

Comment: Using Inkscape to something which needs CAD or special floorplan software. is a nightmare. Floorplan software has 2 bonuses: 3D visualization and furniture collection. 2D free CAD example: turbocad.com/content/doublecad-xt-v5 Free floorplan software is also available: icecreamapps.com/blog/best-free-floor-plan-creator-2018. Then there are plenty of low cost commercial packages. Cloud versions are easy to start, but beware: Many of them do not allow any imports and exports can be lores JPG only.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you would like to change the page size.

To do this, go to File > Document properties, first tab. There, either select a size that matches your needs, or enter a custom size.

To work in a specific scale, there are a couple of tools available, e.g. the https://gitlab.com/Moini/inkscape-realscale-extension will allow you to resize your contents to a line of known length. It will also draw a scale indicator.